# PROC HTTP multipart POST request

Tags: http, post, sas, multipartform-data, proc

I end up getting a 400 Bad request when I run the below SAS code

```
proc http 
        url = "&base_uri/repository/container/&containerAID/&version/assetgroup/&agaid/upload"
        method="post"
        in="../dataraw/ae.zip"
        ct="multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------989556876368242564784888";
    debug level = 3;
        headers 'Authorization'="Bearer &ACCESS_TOKEN" ;
run;
```

Not sure why it won't go thru.

Comment: What does the log show? How did you arrive at the url and parameters?

Comment: they are defined prior to running this PROC into macro variables. The macro variables resolve correctly. There are multiple GET requests i run which give me the 200 OK message in the log. Only when I try the POST I get a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: the log.....

> POST /fws/api/repository/container/REDACTED/4/assetgroup/REDACTED/upload HTTP/1.1

> User-Agent: SAS/9

> Host: IHAVEREDACTEDTHIS.com

> Accept: */*

> Connection: Keep-Alive

> Content-Length: 23

> Authorization: Bearer <REDACTED>

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------989556876368242564784888

       
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2023 20:46:07 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1282
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: nginx